# How to execute a python program (with a GUI) from Emacs?

Tags: python, spacemacs

I'm trying to test a program written in Python with a front panel generated with Qt Designer (converted from .ui to .py using pyuic4). I can make the following code work outside Emacs, from a terminal (it is just a main window with some labels and buttons):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from panelSimple import Ui_VentanaPrincipal

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_VentanaPrincipal()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    miVentana = Window()
    miVentana.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would like to execute this code from within Emacs, but when I send the buffer to the Python interpreter, and it opens an "Inferior Python" buffer, nothing happens.

On the other hand, if I don't use any graphical user interface, python programs work very well.

**Is it possible to make my program's GUI execute from inside Emacs?**

I started using Spacemacs with its default settings. For my tries I select a virtual environment (with PyQt4 installed), and then I send the buffer to the interpreter. I don't know what other information could be useful to answer my question.

Comment: You didn't try reproducing what you've been doing outside Emacs inside it by using `M-x shell` and entering the same command?

Comment: I tried with M-x shell and it works. And I also tried deleting the "if __name__ == '__main__':" sentence (as @elethan suggest in his answer) and it works the way I wanted, inside Emacs.

Comment: If I `print(__name__)` before the if, it writes `__main__`. But then, nothing inside the if executes. Do you know why?

Comment: I'll answer myself: from python-shell-send-buffer (C-c C-c): `With prefix ARG allow execution of code inside blocks delimited by "if __name__== '__main__':"`. So SPC u m s b in Spacemacs or C-u C-c C-c works. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use C-u C-c C-c. This allows you to run your script in an inferior Python buffer, and executes the code in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. I am not sure why, but when you simply send the script to the shell with C-c C-c without the prefix argument, it won't execute the code in the   `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. This works for me at least, using the default Python mode from python.el in Emacs 24

Comment: At first C-u C-c C-c wasn't working for me because Spacemacs changes the argument (C-u) to (SPC u). After I realized it, it worked. The help from python-shell-send-buffer (C-c C-c) says explicitly: `With prefix ARG allow execution of code inside blocks delimited by "if __name__== '__main__':"`. Thank you!